# Alternative to Docuement Centers

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, document-center

I am currently using SharePoint Foundations which does not have access to the Document Center sit template. The company likes the idea of having a place to put their finalized documents.

I was think of creating a site collection that would have document libraries for their "final documents". Has anyone tried this idea or have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That should work for most needs. You don't have some of the template features for the look and feel, and a lot of the advanced document management stuff isn't in Foundations, but basic document libraries are there and that works for most people's needs if they just want a repository.